# How to hide/dismiss a notification in Planet Zoo?

Tags: planet-zoo

In Frontier's "Planet Zoo", is it possible to dismiss/hide a notification, or do you just need to wait for the game to finish letting the event play out?

Basically, one of my animals is about to have a baby. Great. In the meantime I'm trying to do stuff but this notification is floating over my other windows and I can't figure out how to either move the other windows (you can't seem to drag the 'help'/infopedia popup it seems like) or make the popup notification go away.

So, basically, the game shows me this helpful notification:

[image: The notification...]

If I click on the little box with the arrow, it triggers the animal camera. If I click the body of the notification, nothing happens. If I click the icon, it removes the notification, but instead brings up the 'notification timeline' dialog/modal which is also floating in front of everything and just makes the problem worse:

[image: Not helpful...]

**Is it possible to completely dismiss the notification in some way?** I know that it's possible to configure the notifications to not show for certain events. However I find the notification useful ... but not for longer than it takes for me to recognize the event and decide if I care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 1.3 update.

You'll now be able to dismiss zoo alerts using the new trash can icon.

[Source](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/threads/planet-zoo-update-1-3-and-australia-pack-out-now.553369/)

```
Dismiss Functionality for Zoo Alerts
    Added the ability to dismiss zoo alerts by clicking on a new trash can button or selecting the cross icon on the alert notification.
```

Comment: I've added an official source in there for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The events don't stay up for very long. If you're busy doing something else, it'll be gone before you realize - IMO.

There is also a bit of a delay between clicking on the button and the popup menu opening. If you double click, it shuts pretty much immediately. Your mileage may vary on a lower framerate as the game does sometimes chug along and is generally less responsive.

I do miss a right click to dismiss (it's an ingrained Civ reflex) but dismissing notification isn't *that* cumbersome either.

Comment: I have close to a hundred peafowl. As far as I can tell they're born pregnant. The notification just about never disappears.